# RethinkDB - Using getNearest() with eqJoin()

Tags: javascript, database, rethinkdb

This works as expected, get all "check ins" at a location

```
r.table('places').eqJoin('checkinId', r.table('checkins'))
```

And this works as expected, get all locations near a point.

```
r.table('places').getNearest(r.point(-122.1634581999,47.7542651), { index : 'places.location' })
```

But this returns an empty array, get all locations near a point, and join check ins.

```
r.table('places').getNearest(r.point(-122.1634581999,47.7542651), { index : 'places.location' }).eqJoin('checkinId', r.table('checkins'))
```

Is there a different way I should be joining the second table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `getNearest` returns a stream of the format `{distance: <number>, doc: <doc>}`, so you probably have to replace `checkinId` in `eqJoin` with `r.row("doc")("checkinId")`

So something like

```
r.table("places").getNearest(...).eqJoin(r.row("doc")("checkinId"), r.table("checkins"))
```

The reason why nothing is returned is because `eqJoin` behaves like a SQL inner joins, meaning that if no match is found, the left document is not returned.